# split mysql field with firstname and lastname into 2 php echo

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, mysqli

I have a field in mysql where I store the firstname and lastname in one example

```
John Smith
```

I want to display only the firstname john in some cases and only the lastname in other cases but obviously if I run the follow query I get the complete field text like  John Smith

```
$username=mysqli_real_escape_string($datacenter,$_POST['username']);
$check=mysqli_query($datacenter, "
SELECT * 
FROM `users` 
WHERE `username` = '$username' 
LIMIT 1");
if(mysqli_num_rows($check)>0){
while($display= mysqli_fetch_assoc($check)) {
```

to display it I run

```
<?php echo $display['fullname']?>


Echo : John Smith
```

How to display only John or only Smith ?

Comment: Well the real answer is go back and save these 2 as 2 seperate columns on your database

Comment: Yeah the problem is that I have a lot of users already

Comment: Then a simple look at the manual would be the next best solution. [Maybe at `explode()` for example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: How much [research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: When you are PRO is easy but how about beginners ? Otherwise I would not have been asking here

Comment: You dont have to be a PRO to read the manual. In fact that is how you move up the path from Noob to PRO

Comment: Might be useful to actually give an answer that points out the utility of `explode()` instead of lecturing about reading the manual, as important as that may also be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best would be to alter the table and add `first_name` and `last_name` and then update it:

```
UPDATE `users` SET `first_name` = SUBSTRING_INDEX(`fullname`, ' ', 1),
                   `last_name`  = SUBSTRING_INDEX(`fullname`, ' ', -1)
```

Or to select them:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(`fullname`, ' ', 1)  as `first_name`,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(`fullname`, ' ', -1) as `last_name`
       WHERE `username` = '$username' LIMIT 1
```

In PHP (or assign to variables):

```
echo explode(' ', $display['fullname'])[0];
echo explode(' ', $display['fullname'])[1];
```

Comment: is there any way to just split and echo it ?

Comment: I told you how, you use `explode()` and the manual of course to work out how to use `explode()`

Comment: Big YES to that

Comment: Might want to check for cases with more than one space separated name, e.g. "Linus Van Pelt", and flag those for manual review. You can also check that if you concatenate firstname and lastname with a space in between does that equal the original name, and if not take a look at it to see why.